# Moodle Cache error 3.0

Tags: caching, moodle

I am using Moodle 3.0, i installed "klass" theme and since then i started having issues.

for example newly created categories are not showing, some courses' behavior is weird and i can't change the theme anymore.

when i try to purge all caches i get the below error:

[image]

i tried deleting the cache folder to fix it it did not work.

any input?

Comment: Check the folder permissions - https://docs.moodle.org/29/en/Installing_Moodle#Create_the_.28moodledata.29_data_directory

Comment: thanks Russel i already checked that and it fixed the issue. the weird thing is that i have been using the site for more than 6 month now and suddenly this happened.